# Basinhopping algorithm returns 'RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars'

Tags: algorithm, optimization, scipy, runtime, warnings

Hei everyone. So, I'm having a problem with basinhopping algorithm. It works quite OK for all my other datasets, but for a specific one, it returns this error I mentioned in the title. The goal is to solve a non-linear system of three equations, with three unknowns (x[0], x[1], x[2]). Code is summarized bellow:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping

xmin = [-10 , -1, 0]
xmax = [10, 1, 1]
bnds = np.array([(low, high) for low, high in zip(xmin, xmax)])
x0 = np.array([0,0,0])
Solution = np.zeros((len(Vp),3))
kwargs = dict(bounds=bnds, tol=1.0e-16)

for ii in range(0,len(Vp)):
    def fun(x):
         return  ((C[1]*x[1] + C[2]*x[2] + C[3]*x[0]*x[2] + C[4]*x[1]**2 + 
                 C[5]*x[1]*x[2] + C[6]**x[2]**2 - Vp[ii])**2 +  
                 (D[1]*x[1] + D[2]*x[0]*x[1] - Vs[ii])**2 + 
                 (E[1]*x[1] + E[2]*x[0]**2 +
                 E[3]*x[0]*x[1]- Density[ii])**2)  

    sol = basinhopping(fun, x0, minimizer_kwargs = kwargs)
    Solution[ii,:] = np.asarray(sol.x)
    x0 = Solution[ii,:]
```

The values of C, D, E, Vp, Vs and Density are

```
C = [ 0.        ,  0.23602278, -0.03112353, -0.00200731,  0.12631723,
    0.01686503, -0.03604464]
D = [ 0.        , -0.01411336, -0.00048822]
E = [  0.00000000e+00,   2.74052684e-02,  -2.51367338e-05,
     9.57081839e-04]

Vp = [ 0.026575, -0.076332, -0.063064, -0.058712, -0.103915, -0.145887,
   -0.080618, -0.079216, -0.171163, -0.115634, -0.076444]
Vs = [ 0.002064, -0.000847,  0.002788,  0.004255,  0.003588,  0.003474,
    0.001675,  0.004111,  0.006459,  0.004753,  0.009658]
Density = [ 0.001782, -0.001433, -0.002109, -0.002997, -0.009515, -0.005077,
   -0.004877, -0.013798, -0.010524, -0.015607, -0.017562]
```

I think I may be missing something quite basic here, because this code has been working so far. I realize this error is usually related to dividing by zero, but I do not see as it is happening in this case... Any tips?

Comment: When you report a python error, always include the *complete*  traceback (i.e. the complete error message).  It includes useful information, including which line triggered the error.

Comment: Hei Warren, thanks for pointing this out. The error line reads:

'__main__:79: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars'

Comment: Thanks.  It would also help if you could modify your code in the question to be a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).